# The annotations not working in maven project

Tags: java, selenium, maven, junit, automated-tests

I hope everyone is going well, i have following 2 classes under src/test/java/com.selenium.test:

AppTest.java:

```
package com.selenium.test;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class AppTest {

WebDriver driver;

//Before function
@Before
public void Begin()
{
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@After
public void End()
{
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

and the second class  Projectest.java:

```
package com.selenium.test;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Apptest2 extends AppTest{

@Test
public void testWebsite(){
    System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object({}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 }
```

in cmd i access to the project folder and i write this command "mvn test", this is the output that i have:

```
C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\SeleniumTest>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ---------------------< com.selenium:SeleniumTest >----------------------
[INFO] Building SeleniumTest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SeleniumTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is 
platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SeleniumTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SeleniumTest ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is 
platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SeleniumTest ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ SeleniumTest ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.106 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-04-06T21:43:07+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is also my "pom.xml" file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>SeleniumTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>


  <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

The problem is that when i put the @test code in the first class like this:

```
package com.selenium.test;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class AppTest {
WebDriver driver;

//Before function
@Before
public void Begin()
{
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public void testWebsite(){
    System.out.println("Starting test " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}

@After
public void End()
{
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

when i write the command mvn test, i have this output:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO]  T E S T S
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO]
 [INFO] Results:
 [INFO]
 [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

but when i wrote the @test in the second class as shown above, i have this resultat:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO]  T E S T S
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO]
 [INFO] Results:
 [INFO]
 [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

I didn't understand where the problem is, can anyone please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: First `src/test/java/com.selenium.test` this is not a correct package `src/test/java/com/selenium/test` second the name `Apptest2` does not follow naming convention. It must end with `*Test.java` and pay attention to case so change it into `AppTwoTest`... instead ... And you should rename your `AppTest` because it's not a test itself it's only a base class for other tests so for example `AppTestBase` ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @khmarbaise , i've changed the name of my class test to HelloTest and everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to run "mvn clean compile" first (usally I run "mvn clean install' all the time). I guess problem is that your new class with new @Test annotation was not recompiled. I see that

[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (**default-testCompile**) @ SeleniumTest

**[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date**

Comment: No that's not the problem here ...apart from that using `mvn clean install` is most of the time not neccessary only if you like to install your project in your local cache...to consume it by another project... furthermore if you like to run your unit test you should do `mvn clean test`. Doing `mvn clean compile` and afterwards `mvn clean install` repeats several parts of the life cycle...

Answer (score 0):

First `src/test/java/com.selenium.test` this is not a correct package `src/test/java/com/selenium/test` second the name `Apptest2` does not follow naming convention. It must end with `*Test.java` and pay attention to case so change it into `AppTwoTest`... instead ... And you should rename your `AppTest` because it's not a test itself it's only a base class for other tests so for example `AppTestBase`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you simply haven't configured maven-surefire-plugin to be able to find your Test classes.

Also, you might want to use "Selenium-Jupiter" instead of the configuration you have in your Pom.  Just my opinion.

Here are the examples: https://github.com/bonigarcia/selenium-jupiter-examples